# Angular2 decorators are not defined

Tags: typescript, angular, decorator, webpack, injectable

My project builds with webpack but when I host the app from localhost I get an error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: __decorate is not defined.

Initially i get the error with the Injectable() decorator.  But when I uncomment that I get the same error but with extends.

Ive created a repo that duplicates the errors.
https://github.com/shawnrmoss/decorators

I suspect it has something to do with typings since the problem started when I had to change those definitions.
typings_orig.json has the original typings definitions

Im no sure what is going on.  Hopefully someone can shine a light on this and help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give us more details about what you use? ES5, ES6, TypeScript?

Comment: Sure:
  angular 2 2.0.0.0-beta.0,  typescript 1.7.5, es6

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: __decorate is not defined(anonymous function) @ auth.service.ts:6(anonymous function) @ auth.service.ts:87__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 435ddfde67fa15c11a9e:50(anonymous function) @ main.ts:1__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 435ddfde67fa15c11a9e:50webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 435ddfde67fa15c11a9e:21(anonymous function) @ main.bundle.js:1

Comment: Everything was working fine.  Then I had a hard drive fail.  Had to download the project from our repository and reinstall the node_modules.  Since then I get this error

Comment: Thanks! Did you include the `angular2-polyfills.js` file?

Comment: I started with the angularclass starter kit.  In the vendor ts file it has this // (these modules are what are in 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills' so don't use that here)
import 'es6-promise';
import 'zone.js/lib/browser/zone-microtask';

Comment: `decorate` makes me thing about a problem at the reflect-metadata library (see `Reflect.decorate`) which is contained into `angular2-polyfills.js`... That's why I asked you for

Comment: That starter kit is horrible. It is like starting off with a sizable legacy code base and 10 years if technical dept with horrible practices ingrained instead of starting a brand new project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you don't import include the Reflect-metadata library into your project. This library is provided by Angular thanks to the `angular2-polyfills.js` file. This library contains both ZoneJS and Reflect-metadata.

This library is used by decorators, specially the `@Injectable` one. They internally use the `Reflect.decorate` function.

From your comment, it seems that you only import es6-promise and zone-microtask...

> I started with the angularclass starter kit. In the vendor ts file it has this // (these modules are what are in 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills' so don't use that here) import 'es6-promise'; import 'zone.js/lib/browser/zone-microtask';

This article could help you and look for `Reflect.decorate`:

- http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-reflection-javascript-typescript

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I read through the article you provided but Im still at a loss.  I create a stripped down repo that duplicates the error Im getting https://github.com/shawnrmoss/decorators.git